# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn Checkbox element IsChecked with Converter TwoWay binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, object

I have an DatagridTemplate Column containing an Checkbox which through an converter gets checked when a property on my ItemSource is "J" and unchecked when the property is "N".

This works, but now I want the property to be set to "J" if I select the checkbox or "N" when I deselect it.

My Column:

```
<local:JNConverter x:Key="JNConverter" />

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox Name="auto" HorizontalAlignment="center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Autonummering, Converter={StaticResource JNConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My Converter:

Public Class JNConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

```
Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value.ToString.ToLower = "j" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    If CType(value, Boolean) Then
        Return "J"
    Else
        Return "N"
    End If
End Function
```

End Class

My Itemsource is a List(Of Attribuut), Attribuut :

```
Public Class Attribuut
    Inherits DependencyObject

     Public Shared AutonummeringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Autonummering", GetType(String), GetType(Attribuut))

    Public Property Autonummering As String

End Class
```

So how would I "reverse" bind the clicking on the checkbox to change the Autonummering property to "J" or "N"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the IsChecked-Binding to `PropertyChanged`, that should do it.

Comment: Thats was the problem! Thank you.